# Preg_match with regular expressions?

Tags: php, preg-match

Im trying to catch a posted variable with name that begins with 'price' and ends with a number 0-9 and save the number in a variable `$matches`. For some reason, the code i have isnt catching it, so obviously my syntax is off. Heres my code..

```
elseif (preg_match('price/[1-9]/', $field_name, $matches)) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/^price([0-9])$/', $field_name, $matches)
```

The `$matches[1]` will give you the number.

Comment: Perfect that did it. One more quick question.. After setting this `$num = $matches[0];` How would i go about doing this (this syntax is incorrect but you get the point): `$price = $_POST['price$num'];`

Comment: `$price = $_POST['price'.$num];`

Comment: If it begins with price, regex should be `/^price([0-9])/`. And i've got a question. Are you generating the HTML `<input>`s for each price?

Comment: @fcingolani Yes, that's true.

Comment: @fcingolan I have a javascript that allows the user to add as many inputs as they want, each time they add, it adds a group of four (price, quantity, etc) with the named appended with the number. So now i have to process these and email them formatted in groups so i need to extract the number and match it with the others

Comment: @jonah have you tried using `<input name="prices[$id]"`? Then you could iterate it like `foreach($_POST['prices'] as $id => $value)`

Comment: @fcingolani Yeah but then id have the problem that no one just puts in price, its a group of price, qunatity, etc.

Comment: @jonah then `name="data[$n][prices]"`, `name="data[$n][qty]"`, `name="data[$n][foo]"` will get you an iterable array of `Array ( [price] => a [qty] => b [comment] => c )` hashes.